# Why does “npm install <package_name> —save or yarn add <pakage_name> “ rewrite node-modules files?

Tags: react-native, npm, nodes, npm-install, yarnpkg

In my project I had changed some file inside the nodemodule folder. But after I installed new packages , my previous changes are removed. All the modules are overwritten

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want to make changes to a npm package, you need to clone it to a different location. But first you probably want to clone the repo on github.

Let's assume that you have a github account already, and are logged in. If you choose a repo, like https://github.com/lever/planer You will see a fork button near top right. Click this and it will fork the repo under your account. Then go to your copy of the repo, and click the `clone or download` button. Copy the repo name to the clipboard.

At your command line, cd to a suitable location, such as ~/projects and type this

```
git clone https://github.com/<yourname>/planer
cd planer
sudo npm link
npm install
```

This will copy the repo to your local environment, and the `npm link` command tells npm that this repo is the one to use for `planer`. One more step is to cd to your project where you are using `planer`, and type this command:

`npm link planer`

At this point it is linked into your project, and you can modify the code as you like (in `~/projects/planer`) and test your app. You may need to build the package each time so that your changes go through.

Comment: Thank you Mikkel, But why rewrite all the node modules after npm install pacakgename —save ? I need to install particular package only. But it’s installed all the node modules which I have installed

Comment: Basically node_modules is a part of the build system, and is owned by npm, so you shouldn't modify anything in there. How it exactly works is up to npm.

Comment: Mikkel let’s think we have to change inside the xcode code. Like this link issue.   https://github.com/shoutem/ui/issues/134    Can i do it using fork?

Comment: shoutem/ui is an npm module like any other, but I think the xcode you are referring to is elsewhere

Comment: Thank you. I will try and let you know my project large scale app. Now I have to change lot of codes using fork manually.